# What are the true usages of HTML's <link> tags?

Tags: html

Every once in a while I will see a bunch of `<link>` elements in code:

```
<link rel="Home" href="/" title="Page d'accueil de Babysun" />
<link rel="Index" href="/" />
<link rel="Top" href="/" title="Babysun / Accueil Babysun - Babysun" />
<link rel="Search" href="/content/advancedsearch" title="Recherche Babysun" />
<link rel="Shortcut icon" href="/extension/ezwebin/design/babysun/images/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="Copyright" href="/ezinfo/copyright" />
<link rel="Author" href="/ezinfo/about" />
```

The link element is described as:

> The `<link>` tag defines the **relationship between a document and an external resource**. The `<link>` tag is most used to link to style sheets.

(emphasis mine)

What external resources? SEO?

If so, what does Google care about:

```
<link rel="Home" ...>
<link rel="Index" ...>
<link rel="Top" ...>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rel` is not limited to the `<link>` tag, it can also be used with `<a>`.

According to the w3c

> This attribute describes the relationship from the current document to
>   the anchor specified by the href attribute. The value of this
>   attribute is a space-separated list of link types.

You can find the common link-types here :

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.12

And even in these, only the SEO ones (nofollow, noindex, canonical) have some real leverage (although Google is known to ignore them when he wants to.)

This sentence summarizes well the types :

> User agents, search engines, etc. **may** interpret these link types in a
>   **variety** of ways. For example, user agents may provide access to linked
>   documents through a navigation bar.

This being quite a mess, the Microformats project tries to standardize their usage (Microformats are not limited to rel.) You can find draft and specs [here](http://microformats.org/wiki/Main_Page). The coolest one is `rel="tag"` ([here](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel-tag)).

Answer (score 1):

as the spec defines it:

> ...it conveys relationship information that may be rendered by user
>   agents in a variety of ways (e.g., a tool-bar with a drop-down menu of
>   links)

further on, you can read about [link types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-links), and extract some specific information on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a bit more about the  tag on this pages:

http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/use-links

**Google, for example,** uses the **rel="canonical"** to identify each one of the pages with the same content should be indexed by search engines.

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394